# Not able to fetch an array of results from angular2 service

Tags: angular2-services

This is my service code to fetch an array of results:

```
  getIndustries(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${IndustriesService.BASE_URI}/?searchTerm=`)
                    .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                    .catch((err: any) => Observable.throw('Server Error'));
  }
```

Below is my components constructor and the method to communicate with the above defined service.

```
  protected searchData: Array<Industry>;
  constructor( private completerService: CompleterService,
               private route: ActivatedRoute,
               private industriesService: IndustriesService) { 
      this.fetchIndustryCodes();
    }

  private fetchIndustryCodes(): Subscription {
    return this.route.params
      .switchMap((industries: Industry[]) => this.industriesService.getIndustries())
      .subscribe((industries_data: Industry[]) => {
        this.searchData = industries_data
      });
  }
```

when I am trying to print this searchData in the constructor it prints a Subscription object. I am not sure how to fetch the data through above mentioned subscription.

Any direction on this would be a great help!

Comment: looks like you are supposed to be sending your search term as a url parameter also, but yet you never populate it "?searchTerm=" ... you need to put your search term variable in there.

Comment: also, are you planning on swallowing any errors that are returned from your service call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far I have understood, you want to use `searchData` in your constructor, but you are unable coz the async call takes time and the code in the constructor executes before `fetchIndustryCodes()` completes. If this is the case, then why don't you `subscribe` and wait in the constructor itself?

```
constructor( private completerService: CompleterService,
           private route: ActivatedRoute,
           private industriesService: IndustriesService) { 

            this.fetchIndustryCodes().subscribe(
            (industries_data) => {
                this.searchData = industries_data;
                // whatever you want to do here.
            }, (err) => {console.log("error here")});
}


 private fetchIndustryCodes(): Observable<type> {
    return this._activatedRoute.params
        .switchMap((industries) => this.industriesService.getIndustries())
        .catch((err) => {console.log(err); return "service error";})
}
```

Comment: Tried above solution, I think am almost there. it's giving error at this.searchData = industry_data; error is: [ts]
Type 'string | Observable<any>' is not assignable to type 'Industry[]'. 
Note: I have declared the searchData as protected searchData: Array<Industry>;

Comment: Try with the return type of `fetchIndustryCodes()` as `Observable<Array<Number>>` looking into why orred `Observable<string>`  is causing problem in subscription

Comment: Although `Observable<Array<number>> | any` works fine, Obviously :P Leaving from work, please comment if you can fix this type mismatch error,  or else will see tomorrow.

Comment: Also I didn't have the Industry type so I had taken the type as Array<number>